# Understanding the usage of וגומר and וכולו

Tags: words, etymology, provenance

Why are the terms וגומר and וכולו used instead of just writing out the rest of the sentence? When were these terms first instituted?

Comment: Why are abbreviations used? Because it's quicker?

Comment: Why does English use `etc.,`, `[...]`, and `[et. al.]`?

Comment: Where do you see them?

Comment: I always thought that וכו' is short for וכולי, not וכולו. I have also seen it written out that way sometimes.

Comment: @ba Wikimilon [writes as follows](http://he.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%95%27): מילה הבאה בסוף רשימת דברים, ומציינת שניתן היה להמשיך ולמנות אותם. קיצור של וכוליה, "וכולו" בארמית.

Answer (score 2):

I have always understood that וגומר is used when abbreviating a pasuk - lists etc. take וכולי

Comment: You're answering the question that this one isn't but that would, in fact, be more interesting.